# How to make it so that the bot checks if that mentioned user is in a voice chat

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is my code, it won't work. It keeps saying that I'm not in a voice channel when im clearly am.

```
if(message.author.id !== "247227873734295562") return message.channel.send("no perms")
    const mUser = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
    let isDeafened = false; 
   if(!mUser) {
       return message.channel.send("You need to mention a user!");
   }
   
     if(!mUser.voice) {
     message.channel.send(`${mUser} isn't in a voice channel.`);
     return;
   }
   if(mUser.voice) {
       mUser.setDeaf(true)
       return;
   }
```

PLease and tahnk you

Answer (score 0):

Check the channel of the VoiceState; so, `mUser.voice.channel` or `mUser.voice.channelId`. If it exists, the user is in a voice channel. If it's null, the user is not in a voice channel.